# Await setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

I am new to Javascript and unable to understand the Async/Await behaviour.
I have read that Await is for Promises and should not affect non-promise items.
But when I used Await with `setTimeout` it behaved differently.

```js
async function foo() {
  console.log('FIrst');
  await setTimeout(()=>{console.log('timeout')},1000);
  console.log('Second');
} 
foo();
console.log('Three');
```

```
//Output is
//FIrst
//Three
//Second
//timeout
```

But when I remove await it gives

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('FIrst');
  setTimeout(()=>{console.log('timeout')},1000);
  console.log('Second');
} 
foo();
console.log('Three');
```

```
//Output is
//FIrst
//Second
//Three
//timeout
```

So my question is in first code if it's actually waiting for settimeout to finish then why is it printing `Second` before `timeout`. Shouldn't it be `timeout` then `Second`

EDIT:  Some comments say it is due to microtask Queue but can you explain the flow between callback queue and Microtask Queue.

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: @Andy If await works for non-promises like it does for promises then I was expecting 
Output as
//FIrst
//Three
//timeout
//Second

Comment: "*it's actually waiting for settimeout to finish*" it's not. In that, it won't wait until the callback is triggered. It would "wait for setTimeout to finish" in that the call will resolve, the callback will be registered with a timer. The `await` just adds the rest of the function to the microtask queue, hence why "Three" is printed.

Comment: "*If await works for non-promises like it does for promises*" it doesn't. I don't know where you got that idea but your experiment also directly disproves it.

Comment: const delay = (duration) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
This method would be a common practice of using await with setTimeout